# How to let pandas groupby add a count column for each group after applying list aggregations?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": ["apple", "banana", "apple", "banana", "banana"],
                   "col_2": [1, 4, 8, 8, 6],
                   "col_3": [56, 4, 22, 1, 5]})
```

on which I apply a groupby operation that aggregates multiple columns into a list, using:

```
df = df.groupby(['col_1'])[["col_2", "col_3"]].agg(list)
```

Now I want to additionally add a column that for each resulting group adds the number of elements in that group. The result should look like this:

```
{"col_1": ["apple", "banana"],
 "col_2": [[1, 8], [4, 8, 6]],
 "col_3": [[56, 22], [4, 1, 5]]
 "count": [2, 3]}
```

I tried the following from reading other Stack Overflow posts:

```
df = df.groupby(['col_1'])[["col_2", "col_3", "col_4"]].agg(list).size()

df = df.groupby(['col_1'])[["col_2", "col_3", "col_4"]].agg(list, "count")

df = df.groupby(['col_1'])[["col_2", "col_3", "col_4"]].agg(list).agg("count")
```

But all gave either incorrect results (option 3) or an error (option 1 and 2)

How to solve this?

Comment: Check `.agg([list, 'count'])`

Comment: @Shubham Sharma This kinda works, but gives a (duplicate) count column and a list column for each of the groupby columns. I was looking for something that just appends 1 single column to the dataframe with the count of each group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `named` aggregation

```
d = {c:(c, list) for c in ('col_2', 'col_3')}
df.groupby('col_1').agg(**{**d, 'count': ('col_2', 'size')})
```

Or we can separately calculate the `size` of each group, then `join` it with the dataframe that contains the columns aggregated as lists

```
g = df.groupby('col_1')
g[['col_2', 'col_3']].agg(list).join(g.size().rename('count'))
```

---

```
            col_2      col_3  count
col_1                              
apple      [1, 8]   [56, 22]      2
banana  [4, 8, 6]  [4, 1, 5]      3
```

Comment: @Peter The first option can be simplified to `df.groupby('col_1').agg(**{'col_2': ('col_2', list), 'col_3': ('col_3', list), 'count': ('col_2', 'size')})` in case you don't have too many columns that need to be aggregated to list

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another performant approach to solve the problem:

```
x = df.groupby('col_1')
x.agg({ 'col_2': lambda x: list(x),'col_3': lambda x: list(x),}).reset_index().join(
    x['col_2'].transform('count').rename('count'))
```

**Output**

```
    col_1   col_2       col_3         count
0   apple   [1, 8]      [56, 22]        2
1   banana  [4, 8, 6]   [4, 1, 5]       3
```

Comment: Yes I know I could get count separately in this way, But I was more looking for functionality that lets me run the list aggregations like in my question, and at the same time appends a single count column to the DataFrame with the counts for the resulting group

Comment: I added example input and output